# Select statement for 1 table returns new rows then the table actually have

Tags: sql, sql-server

Update: the issue was in saving results into a different table. Apologies, this question should be deleted.

I got this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SubscriberKey,
    'True' as Email_Opens
FROM LN_Journey_21
WHERE SubscriberKey in(
    SELECT
        LN.SubscriberKey
    FROM
        _Job J
        join _Open O on J.JobID = O.JobID 
        join LN_Journey_21 LN on LN.SubscriberKey = O.SubscriberKey
    WHERE 
    J.EmailName LIKE 'IQOS_LN%'
    and j.CreatedDate >= '2021-05-10'
)
```

SubscriberKey is a PK in `LN_Journey_21`.

The results have more rows than `LN_Journey_21` had before running the query, how is that?

Comment: I am sceptical of that, unless there is SQL you haven't included in the above that is in your query. Both the `IN` and `DISTINCT` could only reduce the number of rows Provide us with a full [mre].

Comment: that is the exact query, it adds 500 more rows to a 100k rows table.

Comment: Then, again, take the time to provide us with a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The query should be (most importantly you don't need `DISTINCT` anywhere):

```
SELECT SubscriberKey,
       'True' as Email_Opens
FROM dbo.LN_Journey_21 AS LN
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
    FROM dbo._Job AS J
    INNER JOIN dbo._Open AS O 
    ON J.JobID = O.JobID 
    WHERE O.SubscriberKey = LN.SubscriberKey
    AND J.EmailName LIKE 'IQOS_LN%'
    AND J.CreatedDate >= '20210510'
);
```

Extra rows could be explained by:

- different query than what's posted in your question
- `COUNT` query is more complex than just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.table;`
- data has actually changed between when you ran the `COUNT` query and when you ran this query
- using `NOLOCK` (perhaps you've hidden it from us, or it's used on your `COUNT` query, or both)
- you are relying on the status bar in SSMS, which shows *total rows for the batch* by default, and you other queries that return those additional 500 rows

Like the comments suggest, it would be great if you could show a scenario (e.g. on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk%5D) where `COUNT` produces fewer rows than this query. With the information we have so far, it's not possible, except for situations like those I mentioned above (that list may not be exhaustive, but probably the most common).